# How to make a bash copy of an awk variable?

Tags: linux, bash, awk

Here is a simplified version of my problem.

```
if (echo "AA BB CC" | awk '{ print $1 $2 }' | grep -q "B"); then
   echo $2
fi
```

I would like to make `$2` available in bash, so I can use it elsewhere in the script.

Can that be done?

**Update**

I realized that I had simplified the problem too much. The awk expression should have been `awk '{ print $1 $2 }'` instead of just `awk '{ print $2 }'` which I originally posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `set`:

```
set -- `echo "AA BB CC" | awk '{print $2}'`
case $1 in *B*) echo $1;; esac
```

... or if you used the `awk` just to split the output, let `set` do that part as well:

```
set -- `echo "AA BB CC"`
case $2 in *B*) echo $2;; esac
```

Comment: The `set` command can be used to split a string into tokens. It's a kind of under-documented / esoteric feature but it does come in handy sometimes. See e.g. http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/08/bash-shell-builtin-commands/

Comment: Oh, I should not use `echo` in backticks, but I assume the `echo` was just a placeholder for something less embarrassing.  http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html#echo

Answer (score 1):

Remember the output of awk, test it for the regular expression and print it:

```
output=$( echo "AA BB CC" | awk '{ print $2 }' )
if grep -q B <<< "$output" ; then echo "$output" ; fi
```

Comment: What does `<<<` mean compared to just `<`?

Comment: @SandraSchlichting: after `<`, you specify a file; after `<<<`, you specify a string. They go to the standard input of the command.

Answer (score 0):

You can capture stdout into a variable by using the backtick operator, e.g.

```
a=`echo foo`
echo $a
```

For your example, it would be something like:

```
a=`echo "AA BB CC" | awk '{ print $2 }' | grep -q "B"`
echo $a
```

Comment: Yes, doing that inside awk is the problem, as I have an `if` statement around awk.

Comment: But it needs to be done inside an `if`-statement, and because of `-q` in grep, your `$a` will be empty.

Comment: Just capture the output completely then.  `a=$(echo "AA BB CC" | awk '{print $2}'); case $a in *B*) echo "$a";; esac`